# Using ‘which’ to refer to one specific word

Tags: word-choice

> Being a centre of a **competition**, which **is gripping for people from all around the world**, is a tremendous boost for a promotion of the place.

I wanted to address here that the competion is gripping, not the whole "Being a centre of a competition". So, it does not seem to convey my thought, I guess. 
Maybe without "which"?

> Being a centre of a competition gripping for people from all around the world is a tremendous boost for a promotion of the place.

Answer (score 1):

Your supposition about using the second form of the sentence is correct.

What you're actually doing is not just removing *which* but turning the nonrestrictive clause into a restrictive clause. This removes ambiguity by forcing the phrase to apply to something specific.

---

Another way to express it is it to break it into two sentences:

> Some competitions are gripping for people from all around the world. Being the centre of such a competition is a tremendous boost for the promotion of the place.

(I also used a definite article in front of *centre* and *promotion* since it sounds more natural.)

---

But if I were to interpret what your sentence actually means, I would likely phrase it differently:

> Being the host city of a gripping, worldwide competition promotes the city tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think either of those sentences is very clear.

Part of the problem is with the phrase “gripping for people from all around the world.” With or without the *which*, it’s just too much verbiage between the subject and the predicate. (There is nothing “ungrammatical” about it, but the sentence feels bloated and clumsy.)

I’d suggest something more like:

> Being a centre of such a popular, gripping competition will promote this place tremendously.